# "Good Job, buddy" - nope, bad job - disappear

Tags: discussion, badges, deleted-answers

There is an elusive badge, so difficult to attain that only the *elite* and most humble Stack users can achieve it.

REquest: 
Please do not  delete the questions for users who attain the Reversal badge. I.E if answer achieves the Reversal badge, we should prevent deletion of the question .  *

Sam I am and Diego, both are witness. [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)

[image]

Comment: The badge could be awarded on obvious non-answers which potentially could or should be deleted but that doesn't mean the question was deleted. For example, 10k users can see [Diego's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23166565/426671) which said _You are cheating... this is a question from the coursera's R programming course_ and they received 21 upvotes.  The [quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098699/calculate-the-mean-of-one-column-from-several-csv-files-in-r) remains but it wasn't a worthy answer to stick around - as the community decided when we got 8 NAA flags on it.

Comment: In the case of Diego, it was the answer that was deleted, not the question. Correctly so, because it was not an answer at all. It was clearly a comment.

Comment: Really, the posts in question don't add anything. Don't confuse popularity and a lucky badge with actual usefulness.

Comment: Ok understood , I stand corrected , thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That first one, if you could see the text, it reads:

> You are cheating... this is a question from the coursera's R programming course

That's not even an answer. It was a comment that somehow garnered a lot of upvotes.

---

Many of these questions are just so terrible that **no answer can save them**. So no, it doesn't make any sense whatsoever to allow a Reversal badge to make a question immune from deletion.

Or do you think we really need a question sitting around asking ["Why false!=false returns false?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854358/why-false-false-returns-false-in-java)

Comment: Well, it's a better question than lots we get... (which is not saying much, sad to say).